# why is a css file i didnt import effecting one of my file

Tags: css, reactjs, import

I was working on react on a project i was tasked on working the admin page and my other team mate was working on the public page, again i was tasked on merging it. i never worked with react and never merged before i faced a lot of issues so i manually merging it. Functionally it works the only problem is the css style used in the public page is effecting the admin page how do i know this ? i saw it in the console that not only its using the once i imported but that of the public page. could anyone tell me how to prevent that. i checked if the css was imported on the index.js or in the app.js but its not imported there too. any suggestion idea or recommendation, i will take in to consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that it's similar to what I am working on, where there are multiple CSS style sheets, but not all of them are actively affecting the page at all times and there are some designated to specific parts within a page.

We have it set up in a directory though and there are multiple layers, so it's kind of hard to help you without knowing the specific project you're referring to since it can be within the code and within a directory?

Long shot, but good luck!